# Which is better MAX function or ORDER BY column_name DESC with LIMIT 1

Tags: mysql

I have one scenario where I want to have max value on date column,

eg. for table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sample_table` (
  `id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOTNULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARYKEY(`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

So I used a query as below:

```
SELECT MAX(created_at) AS latest FROM sample_table;
```

But I was suggested to index created_at column and use following query for faster result

```
SELECT created_at FROM sample_table ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I am clueless which is best way to do so? If second query is better, than why there is inbuilt MAX function

Comment: What does the execution plan say?

Comment: I have to use this query in PHP code, I tried running both queries using phpMyadmin but I get different results(execution time) every time. I am new to this so I am clueless why its showing different results

Comment: He means what does the result of EXPLAIN show.  This is the command to find out how MySQL executes a query internally after all optimization has applied.  They are likely the same.

Comment: **Result of 1st query** 
`id => 1 
select_type => SIMPLE 
type => ALL 
possible_keys => NULL 
key  => NULL 
key_len => NULL 
ref => NULL 
rows => 52134 
Extra => ____`

**2nd query result**
`id => 1 
select_type =>SIMPLE 
type => ALL 
possible_keys => NULL 
key => NULL 
key_len =>NULL 
ref=>NULL 
rows=>50883 
Extra => Using filesort `

Comment: The difference will be noticed after you create the index on 'created_at'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an index on `created_at` and use your first query:

```
SELECT MAX(created_at) AS latest FROM sample_table;
```

The suggestion you got is good in other situations, like if you want a max value of a field that is smaller than certain value. i.e.

```
SELECT created_at FROM sample_table WHERE created_at<"2014-01-01 00:00:00" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: +1 it's also useful if you want other columns from the same row.

Comment: So there might be many such case where 1st query is better or in some place 2nd query, how do I judge it? Is there any reference document where I can get knowledge of these kind of hacks, or any tool where I can test it before using